# how to make 'input.radio' to be not checked in if statements?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/12dkswgd/

I'm trying to choose a gender by elem 'input.radio'

So I made some if sentences, but it's not working.

I don't know why.

Belows are codes that I made. it's not working.

You can see more easier at fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/12dkswgd/

```
html :
male<input type="radio" id="a"></input>
<br/>
female<input type="radio" id="b"></input>


js :
/* these sentences are not working
a = document.getElementById('a');
b = document.getElementById('b');

if(a.checked) {b.checked = false}
if(b.checked) {a.checked = false}
*/

/* these sentences are not working, either.
if(document.getElementById('a').checked) {
    document.getElementById('b').checked = false
} else if(document.getElementById('b').checked) {
    document.getElementById('a').checked = false
    }
*/

/* this sentence is working. */
document.getElementById('a').checked = true;
```

Comment: why do want to do that using javascript when you can get that done using HTML only

Comment: How can you do that with only html??? Is it possible? How? And even if it's possible, I still wonder why my codes are not functioning..

Comment: have provided the fiddle in anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 1:** using `onchange` handler - check [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/qepel/1/edit)

If you want to get it done using JavaScript then one way is like this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/gewala/1/edit):

**Note**: The problem with your JavaScript code was: you were not wrapping the JavaScript code inside any function ( so your code used to run only once ) and you need to handle the radio button click using a handler ( in fiddle its `changeRadio('button')` and with bit more logic)

but as other people have suggested I would prefer HTML way which is more cleaner and simpler :

```
   Male:   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
   Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest case scenario, you shouldn't really require JavaScript to do the toggle if the "name" attribute of the checkboxes are the same.

```
<label>Male<input type="radio" id="a" name="gender"/></label>

<label>female<input type="radio" id="b" name="gender"/></label>
```

notice that i wrapped the checkboxes with `label` so that the text would be clickable as well.

Comment: why did you wrapped elem.input with <label>? usually it is written like this : <label>abc</label><input/>... what is advantage if wrap elem.input with <label>?

Comment: The text and the checkbox control, if wrapped within a label tag, event on the text will be propagated down to the checkbox control. This improves accessibility.

Comment: ... that way a user doesn't have to click"precisely" on the checkbox. The text passes the event down to the "targeted" checkbox control. When html is well-formed, it can save you a lot of "hacks".

Comment: Person who solved my curiosity about js problem was zian. But thanks. Your answer was very helpful to me.It was a better way to solve the problem,

Answer (score 0):

change your html to this:

```
male<input type="radio" name="a" id="a"/>
<br/>
female<input type="radio" name="a" id="b"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
```

And dont use javascript, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need js for this. Just set same `name` on both radios:

```
mail<input type="radio" name="test" id="a" />
<br/>
femail<input type="radio" name="test" id="b" />
```

[**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/12dkswgd/2/)

You need js for this only if you use this radio in an asp `repeater`.

Comment: Radio input this is same close tag. You write invalid html.